# Unable to login AIX via putty, but able to ping

Tags: ssh, putty, aix

I am working on an intranet.

I have some AIX servers, and I use to login them via putty.

It works fine from some workstations, but I am not able to login from one of my windows workstation.

I get connection timeout error.
Although I am able to ping that AIX server from this machine. Also, tracert commands gives results.

Also, I am able to login this AIX server from other machines. Only having problem with one machine only.

I wanted to know how to change the settings of the AIX server so that it allows me to login from all workstations on the network.

Comment: It is probably a firewall issue if you can ping but can't ssh. You say intranet so I guess it is a corporate environment, have you contacted the network department?

Comment: @jaume I have access to the target machine as an admin..can you suggest how to add my workstations' IP in the list with the ones from I am able to connect from?

Comment: I added an answer with my suggestions on how to solve this problem. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Not being able to connect with SSH to a remote computer while ping works, as it is your case, usually points to some sort of packet filtering in place.

SSH access is either blocked by a firewall placed between your workstation and the server, or on the AIX server itself.

In the former case, contact the firewall administrators.

In the latter case check this:

- AIX filters may be active. Read this article:  http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-aixfiltering/index.html to find out and change existing rules to match your needs.
- You may have TCP wrappers installed (http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-tcpwrapper/index.html) and enabled on your AIX system. Look for your workstation's IP in `/etc/hosts.deny` and `/etc/hosts.allow`.

For further troubleshooting use [tcpdump](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.aix.cmds/doc/aixcmds5/tcpdump.htm):

```
tcpdump -n -i en1 src workstationIP and port 22
```

or [iptrace](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21175744) (use `ipreport` to read file `trace.out`):

```
iptrace -a -i en1 -s workstationIP -b -d serverIP -p 22 trace.out
```

to find out whether SSH IP packets from your workstation are arriving at the server. In both commands replace `en1`, `workstationIP` and `serverIP` with the name of the active network interface on the server and the workstation and server IP address.